# bootstrap datepicker fixed at the top of the page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm making a form that has a date picker, I'm using `bootstrap datepicker`

In addition, the main bootstrap field should be hidden, I have three of my own fields, when you click on any of them, the calendar should open, now everything works, the calendar opens, but is fixed at the top of the page. Can I make it open near the fields?

```js
// Initialize datepicker
const dp = $("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
    todayHighlight: true
});

// Show datepicker on <input> click  
$('.input-wrapper > input').on('click', (e) => dp.datepicker("show"));

// On date change
const y  = document.getElementById('year');
const m  = document.getElementById('month');
const d  = document.getElementById('day');
dp.on('changeDate',function(ev){
    const date = dp.datepicker('getDate');
    y.value = date.getFullYear();
    d.value = date.getDate();
    m.value = date.getMonth() + 1;
    dp.datepicker('hide')
})
```

```css
label {
      color: #808694;
      font-family: Montserrat;
      font-size: 10px;
      font-weight: bold;
      letter-spacing: 0;
      line-height: 16px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
}


    
input {
      margin-right: 20px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      background-color: #F4F5F8;
      width: 50px;
}

.span-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-end;
      }
      
span {
        
        color: #808694;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        font-size: 8px;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 0;
        line-height: 16px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
        width: 50px;
}

.main-content {
  min-height: 150vh;
}

.call-form-item-date {
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


<div class="main-content">
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
</div>

<div class="contacts-call-form">
    <form class="js-form" action="{{ route('send-comment') }}">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="call-form-item-date">
                <label for="date">Select a date *</label>
                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <input class="js-form-month" id="month" type="text" name="month">
                    <input class="js-form-day" id="day" type="text" name="day">
                    <input class="js-form-year" id="year" type="text" name="year">
                    <div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" style="display: none">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly />
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <div class="span-wrapper">
          <span for="month">Month</span>
          <span for="day">Day</span>
          <span for="year">Year</span>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to initialize datepicker with the target input selector like day month and year like this: const dp = $("#day")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display date picker near the inputs you should initialize it with id of date inputs like month.

```js
// Initialize datepicker
const dp = $("#month").datepicker({ 
    todayHighlight: true
});

// Show datepicker on <input> click  
$('.input-wrapper > input').on('click', (e) => dp.datepicker("show"));

// On date change
const y  = document.getElementById('year');
const m  = document.getElementById('month');
const d  = document.getElementById('day');

dp.on('changeDate',function(ev){
    const date = dp.datepicker('getDate');
    y.value = date.getFullYear();
    d.value = date.getDate();
    dp.datepicker('hide');
    m.value = date.getMonth() + 1;
})

dp.on('hide',function(ev){
    const date = dp.datepicker('getDate');
    m.value = date.getMonth() + 1;
})
```

```css
label {
      color: #808694;
      font-family: Montserrat;
      font-size: 10px;
      font-weight: bold;
      letter-spacing: 0;
      line-height: 16px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
}


    
input {
      margin-right: 20px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      outline: none;
      border: none;
      background-color: #F4F5F8;
      width: 50px;
}

.span-wrapper {
        display: flex;
        align-items: flex-end;
      }
      
span {
        
        color: #808694;
        font-family: Montserrat;
        font-size: 8px;
        font-weight: bold;
        letter-spacing: 0;
        line-height: 16px;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: center;
        width: 50px;
}

.main-content {
  min-height: 150vh;
}

.call-form-item-date {
  margin-top: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 150px;
}


.input-wrapper{
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


<div class="main-content">
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
  <p>Main content...</p>
</div>

<div class="contacts-call-form">
    <form class="js-form" action="{{ route('send-comment') }}">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="call-form-item-date">
                <label for="date">Select a date *</label>
                <div class="input-wrapper">
                    <div id="datepickerContainer"></div>
                    <input class="js-form-month" id="month" type="text" name="month">
                    <input class="js-form-day" id="day" type="text" name="day">
                    <input class="js-form-year" id="year" type="text" name="year">
                    <div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" style="display: none">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" readonly />
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <div class="span-wrapper">
          <span for="month">Month</span>
          <span for="day">Day</span>
          <span for="year">Year</span>
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: but now if you select a date, it records everything in the month field

Comment: I'll fix it soon

Comment: please check it, i've fixed it, if first hide it and then set month input it works

Comment: yes, everything seems to be fine, thank you)

Comment: I've added hide event for the cases when datepicker show and user does not click and change anything to prevent change month input to full date string